# Is possible to use @Formula on a boolean field?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to know what data types of java support [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-property) of Hibernate,
then I have this example which I don't know how to manage it if it is possible to achievement it.

```
  @Formula("(select boolean_column from table_a where table_a.id = id)"
         + " && " 
         + "(select boolean_column from table_b where table_b.id = id)"") 
  private boolean result;
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*JavaDoc* states

> Defines a formula (derived value) which is a **SQL fragment** that acts as
>   a @Column alternative in most cases.

*SQL fragment* means a piece of `SQL` that can be integrated in the generated statement.

Being that `Formula` manages native SQL statements, yes you can throw in whatever is valid and understood by the *DBMS*, even sub-queries.

As far as I know, only primivite types are supported (which include also `String` and `Date`, for example, and every other type which matches with the table's column data type).

---

In your case, the `SQL` fragment you wrote **isn't** a valid one.

An alternative to that statement might be

```
(select (t1.boolean_column and t2.boolean_column)
from table_a as t1
inner join table_b as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id = id)
```

Comment: I think that you refers other @Formula, because I use one of hibernate https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-property

Comment: @nextsoft I refer to the Hibernate one too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, perhaps could you provide an alternative to use that example If It is not valid, please @LppEdd

Comment: @nextsoft be sure to wrap the statement with parenthesis

Comment: is necessary to add result after (a and b) result?

Comment: @nextsoft I think no, try without it and let me know

Comment: I get the following error : ERROR: syntax error at or near "." my query is:  Formula("(select(ta.boolean_column or ta.boolean_column) result from table_a ta where ta.id = id)") :( why?

Comment: @nextsoft which DBMS (database) are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgresql :( help me!

Comment: @nextsoft try using "table_a as ta". I think PostgreSQL requires the "as"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189321/discussion-between-next-soft-and-lppedd).